# Receiving Amazon Inspector Vulnerability for xlsx, even after it has been updated to the version it asks for, any idea why?

Tags: npm, xlsx, amazon-ecr, sheetjs, npm-vulnerabilities

Currently during my normal scans I am receiving a high vulnerability on my front end ECR image.

It is showing:

[image]

As you can see it registers the installed version equal to the fixed version.

My npm package has the following:

```
"xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.19.3/xlsx-0.19.3.tgz"
```

This is based on the recommendation found here: https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/nodejs/

Is this just a bug or am I missing something? Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: I've seen the exact same thing - did you get it resolved in the end?